# Excel 2010 For Next Loop getting increasingly slower

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks, excel-2010

My question is about adding named range names to data in a sheet (imported from a txt file), deleting excess rows, at the same time.

For that it uses a particularity of the data, which has rows starting with "a" from time to time. The name of the label is given by this row, which is unique. The rows in between these rows starting with "a" should be added named range names.

I am using the below code, but running this code for 1000 rows takes 25 seconds, for the next 1000 rows takes 80-85 seconds etc. Processing time increases exponentially, although it should be equal (?).

Any ideas what I can do to improve the processing time ? I have more than 20k lines per sheet and multiple sheets and right now it can take up to 24hours for just one sheet...

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim named_range_name As String
Dim named_range_location As String
Dim start_row As Integer
Dim end_row As Integer
Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Cells(NumRows + 1, "A").Value = "abcd"
  Range("A1").Select


  For x = 1 To NumRows + 1
     If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "a" And ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then
        start_row = ActiveCell.Row + 1
        named_range_name = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Value
        Else
            If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "a" And ActiveCell.Row <> 1 Then
                end_row = ActiveCell.Row - 1
                named_range_location = "A" & start_row & ":J" & end_row
                Set rng = Range(named_range_location)
                ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=named_range_name, RefersTo:=rng
                start_row = ActiveCell.Row + 1
                named_range_name = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Value
            End If
     End If


     If ActiveCell.Value = "bcd" Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

     If ActiveCell.Value = "efgh" Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

  Next



End Sub
```

Example of the data before the vba script:

```
a008020a018024

bcd

efgh

unu False      3      3     21      7      5.59/  5.09      5.50/  5.01

doi False      2      2     22     11      8.79/  7.99      8.65/  7.87

trei False      4      4     20      5     15.98/ 14.53     11.77/ 10.70

patru False     11      2     22      2     17.59/ 16.00     14.07/ 12.80

cinci False     23      1     23      1     18.28/ 16.62     15.53/ 14.13

saseFalse      0      0     24      1     19.17/ 17.44     18.87/ 17.17
```

The data has multiple blocks with the structure above. Each such block has an unique label, the one starting with "a" followed by a bunch of numbers. The block has variable row count. The data in between 2 such labels has to be... well, labeled.

So if A1 has a label and A12 has the next label, the macro should delete the excess rows in that range and label the remaining data with the label from A1. Then continue to the block between A12 and A20 (for example) and repeat the operation, labeling it with the label from A12.

The problem seems to not reside in the adding range name, but in the loop itself (or the other things populating the loop). I decided to run loop multiple times for just the first 1000 rows, without quitting Excel (so ran it once, then ran it again and so on). The results are the following:

First Run: 28 seconds; Second Run: 113 seconds; Third Run: 293 seconds; Fourth Run: 473 seconds

I've commented the adding of Named Ranges and the execution times are (same scenario, running the loop multiple times for the first 1000 rows, without quitting Excel). The results are:

First Run: 27 seconds; Second Run: 129 seconds; etc.

Help!

Comment: Without deeply analyzing your code I believe Excel takes longer time the more deep down the row is. Maybe you should reconsider your row addressing.

Comment: Below **Application.ScreenUpdating = False** add **Application.Calculation =  xlCalculationManual** and below **Next** add **Application.Calculation =  xlCalculationAutomatic** and below **Application.ScreenUpdating = True** and see what happens.

Comment: Instead of selecting a new cell and use `ActiveCell` in your loop, you could also use `Cells(x,1)` in your loop. I guess selecting a cell 20.000 times takes time as well.

Comment: The data has multiple blocks with the structure of the one given in the original question. Each such block has an unique label, the one starting with "a" followed by a bunch of numbers. The block has variable row count. The data in between 2 such labels has to be... well, labeled. 


So if A1 has a label and A12 has the next label, the macro should delete the excess rows and label the remaining data with the label from A1. Then continue to the block between A12 and A20 (for example) and repeat the operation.

Comment: Having several sheets with 10's of thousands of rows each is not a good idea with excel. Although excel has the room to do it, it is very evident that the process is too slow to be efficient. It may be  better to figure out a way to split the data into different workbooks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can decipher from your code.

1-select A1 and end(down) to last cell+1 then make that cell="abc"

2-You don't know how to start from A2 so you have `if cell starts with a then rowstart=2`

3-loop through every single cell and find either "bcd" or "efgh" and delete the rows

4-Stop loop when you get to your original "abc"

5-Name the remaining range of cells with the value in A1

---

The fastest way I have found to delete row values in a column of rows is using the VBA replace() function and replace the values with blanks, then you can use specialcells to delete the blanks.

I have noticed in your code, that you are using `end(xldown)` that shows me that there are no blanks in your data to start, so replacing those specific cells with blanks will work.

For a couple thousand rows, the result is very fast, not sure about tens of thousands of rows though.

### Check it out.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    With sh
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        With rng
            .Replace what:="bcd", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
            .Replace what:="efgh", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .Range("A2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Name = .Range("A1").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ezwal- you are making comments to other people after my answer, leave comments where they should be, only comment on my answer here.